# Prove that in separable space X $(x_n)$ is convergent to $x_0$ iff $d(x_n, a)$ converges to $d(x_0, a)$ for each $a \in A$where A is dense subset of X

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ a dense countable subset of X.
Then
$$
x_n \rightarrow x_0 \iff \left( \forall_{a \in A} \text{  } d(x_n, a) \rightarrow d(x_0, a)  \right)
$$

My take: for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and $a \in A$ we have that $\exists_N \forall_{n_0 > N} \text{ }d(x_{n_0}, x_0) < \epsilon$. Now using the triangle inequality we obtain:
$$
d(x_n,a) \le d(x_n, x_0) + d(x_0, a) < d(x_0, a) + \epsilon
$$
move $d(x_0, a)$ to left hand side of equation and since d is symmetric:
$$
|d(x_n, a) - d(x_0,a)| < \epsilon
$$
This completes the $\implies$ proof. How can I prove the $\impliedby$?

Comment: I don't see in what the separability is relevant...

Comment: Sorry for possible misleading title @Surb. Perhaps its not limited to separable spaces - it's just a lemma in the proof I am trying to understand("Every separable metric space is homeomorphic to a subset of Hilbert's cube").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $a$ such that $d(x_0,a)<\epsilon/4$. There exists a natural number $N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow |d(x_n,a)-d(x_0,a)|<\epsilon/2$, which implies $d(x_n,a)\leq d(x_0,a)+\epsilon/2$. Then

$$d(x_n,x_0)\leq d(x_n,a)+d(x_0,a)\leq d(x_0,a)+(d(x_0,a)+\epsilon/2)\leq2\epsilon/4+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$$

Hence $x_n\to x_0$

Comment: Thank you. The assumption that A is dense ensured $a \in A$ such that $d(x_0, a) < \epsilon / 4$ exists, right?

Comment: @math_beginner Yeah.

Comment: what if $ \ eps  < 0$